# Meshlab - Coloring all vertices in a mesh at once?

Tags: colors, meshlab

Is it possible to color all vertices in a mesh at once? I only have the option of selecting faces on by one and coloring it

Answer (score 2):

There is a filter called `vertex color filling` which can color all the vertices with a given color.

Comment: I do not see it under Filters. What section is it under

Comment: Under `Color Creation and Processing`. You can also search it with the shortcut `CTRL+F`.